# Passing data to a ViewController that is triggered by an external event

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, url-scheme

I've set up a URL scheme for my application that will open it from a web browser. When received by the application, it presents `AViewController`.

I also have a ViewController, `BViewController` that contains some data. Ideally I would like to be able to pass this data from `BViewController`, to `AViewController` if `BViewController` is open at the time that the URL scheme is activated.

Since the URL scheme triggers a function in `AppDelegate`, I have no opportunity to pass the data from `B` to `A`.

What would be the best way to pass the data along?

The only solutions I can think of so far are:

- Setting and getting a global variable for each piece of data
- When the URL scheme call is received in `AppDelegate`, extracting the data from `B` by accessing the object properties, and setting them in `A`

Neither of these solutions I'm fully happy with, certainly not the first.

Is there be a better way of solving this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you have a model object that is used to populate B, then use that to populate A also

Comment: @AshleyMills I do, but where do I store that object?

Answer (score 1):

If you have…

```
class Object {
   var someData…
}

class BViewController {
    var object: Object!

    func updateObject() { 
        object.someData = …       
    }
}

class AViewController {
    var object: Object!
}
```

Then in AppDelegate, something like this (not real code!)…

```
func handleURL() {

   if let b = rootViewController as? BViewController { 
       let a = AViewController()
       a.object = b.object
       rootViewController = a
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, so similar to my second bullet point. Would this be acceptable practice?

Comment: This is a perfectly cromulent way of doing it.